# Return Array from Javascript Funciton

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to return Array from Javascript but it always return undefined. 
my sample code is

```
$(function () {
    var x = fetchData();
    alert(x);


})


function fetchData() {
    var chartdata = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: '/home/FetchLiveData',
        data: {},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            ObjData = $.parseJSON(data);
            $.each(ObjData, function (i) {
                var TagName = ObjData[i].DisplayTagName;
                var TagValue = ObjData[i].TagValue;
                var dateString = ObjData[i].ValueDateTime.substr(6);
                var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(dateString));
                var month = ('0' + (currentTime.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
                var day = ('0' + (currentTime.getDate() + 1)).slice(-2)
                var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
                var hours = ('0' + (currentTime.getHours() + 1)).slice(-2)
                var min = ('0' + (currentTime.getMinutes() + 1)).slice(-2)
                var sec = ('0' + (currentTime.getSeconds() + 1)).slice(-2)
                var date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hours + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
                var t = {};
                t[TagName] = TagValue;
                t['date'] = date;
                chartdata.push(t);
            });
        }
    });
 return chartdata;
}
```

any my sample JSON String is

```
[{"DisplayTagName":"Temperature","DisplayTagColor":"#000000","TagValue":98.1050300000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607746120)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Temperature","DisplayTagColor":"#000000","TagValue":98.1050300000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607751113)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Temperature","DisplayTagColor":"#000000","TagValue":99.0123000000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607756153)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Temperature","DisplayTagColor":"#000000","TagValue":99.0123000000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607761120)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Temperature","DisplayTagColor":"#000000","TagValue":99.0123000000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607766087)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Temperature","DisplayTagColor":"#000000","TagValue":99.0369000000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607771127)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Temperature","DisplayTagColor":"#000000","TagValue":68.0764200000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607806337)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Temperature","DisplayTagColor":"#000000","TagValue":99.1101300000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607776177)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Temperature","DisplayTagColor":"#000000","TagValue":50.9594700000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607781137)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Temperature","DisplayTagColor":"#000000","TagValue":60.7912600000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607786167)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Temperature","DisplayTagColor":"#000000","TagValue":65.1429600000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607791210)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Temperature","DisplayTagColor":"#000000","TagValue":65.1429600000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607796080)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Temperature","DisplayTagColor":"#000000","TagValue":65.1429600000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607801190)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Density","DisplayTagColor":"#ed4423","TagValue":475134.1000000000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607746303)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Density","DisplayTagColor":"#ed4423","TagValue":475186.2000000000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607751293)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Density","DisplayTagColor":"#ed4423","TagValue":475214.3000000000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607756333)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Density","DisplayTagColor":"#ed4423","TagValue":475243.7000000000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607761300)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Density","DisplayTagColor":"#ed4423","TagValue":475283.7000000000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607766267)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Density","DisplayTagColor":"#ed4423","TagValue":475358.0000000000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607771307)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Density","DisplayTagColor":"#ed4423","TagValue":475382.0000000000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607776357)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Density","DisplayTagColor":"#ed4423","TagValue":475382.0000000000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607781320)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Density","DisplayTagColor":"#ed4423","TagValue":475394.8000000000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607786347)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Density","DisplayTagColor":"#ed4423","TagValue":475417.9000000000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607791300)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Density","DisplayTagColor":"#ed4423","TagValue":475468.9000000000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607796350)\/"},{"DisplayTagName":"Density","DisplayTagColor":"#ed4423","TagValue":475506.7000000000,"ValueDateTime":"\/Date(1485607801407)\/"}]
```

what I'm missing here? any help?

Thanks.

Comment: the ajax call is *asynchronous* - use a *callback* or *promises*...

Comment: ajax is asynchronous. You can't return the data before it is delivered